# javascript return false vs preventdefault focus change

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, focus

https://jsfiddle.net/5f19mz0y/21/

I was searching for the way to prevent the focus escape from input box when the tab key is pressed. Then, I found several ways using `preventDefault()` for onkeydown event. So, since returning false has got same effect of using both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagtion()`, I thought `return false` could be used instead to do the same thing, but after testing it turns out that it doesn't work in such way.

```
<script>
function tab( event ) {

    if ( event.keyCode === 9)
    {
event.preventDefault(); //- focus doesn't change

        }
}
</script>
<input onkeydown="tab(event);">
```

The above code worked as expected; when the tab key is pressed, the focus doesn't change.

```
<script>
function tab( event ) {

    if ( event.keyCode === 9)
    {
return false; //- focus changes

        }
}
</script>
<input onkeydown="tab(event);">
```

For the above code, the focus changes when the tab key is pressed

Could anyone explain me reason for this?

---

**Added**

```
<script>
 function tab( event ) {

    if ( event.keyCode === 9)
    {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();//- focus not changes

        }
}
</script>
<input onkeydown="tab(event);">
```

Considering the case that `stopPropagation()` in `return false` affected the result, just like above, I have also tested with both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`. However, this also works fine just like the one with `preventDefault()`alone; the result is different from the one from `return false`. So, it seems like there are something more in `return false` other than `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

`Returning false` from Javascript event handlers is equivalent to calling both, `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`.

So the difference is that `preventDefault` will only prevent the default event action to occur, i.e. a page redirect on a link click, a form submission, etc. and `return false`will also stop the event flow

[More Detail See Here](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: OP describes that returning false is less limiting (it makes the focus fly away) then simple `e.preventDefault` which makes no sense if what you are saying is true since returning false should, in and of itself "call" prevent default